# Cannot read text from Excel cell?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to grab the string value entered into a specific cell in an excel worksheet.  My code is below:

```
Excel.Application excel_app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook dashboard = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename:@"H:\charge_code_project\test_dashboard.xlsb", ReadOnly: true);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)dashboard.Worksheets[package_type];
Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
string cell_text = worksheet.Cells[10, 10].Text;
```

I receive the following error on the last line when I try to build:

```
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have used this method of reading text from an excel file in previous projects and it has worked, so I know that .Text exists. I see no difference between how I used it previously and how I am using it currently.  I believe I have included all the necessary assembly references and using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using System.IO;
```

I have added the following assembly references:

```
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library 
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
OLE Automation
```

Would anyone help me see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't try Excel interop in .NET Core unless you target version 5.  Which was released a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception since the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object does not have the Text property.

You should use the [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) property to get the value of the cell/range.

Sample code:

```
string cell_text = ((Range)worksheet.Cells[10, 10]).Value.ToString();
```

Updating the answer:
In order this to work, make sure you select 'Embed Interop Types' in Assembly reference properties screen. (see pic).

[image]

Comment: I get the same error when I try .Value as well.  In fact the suggestions that present themselves when I type only show 4 properties, .ToString, .GetType,. GetHashCode, and .Equals.  I know there are more properties than these, yet they somehow seem to be missing.

Comment: Cells[10,10] returns a dynamic type. This is actually Range object. Just cast.

Comment: @EylM nope this does not work with .Net core 6 and interop 15.0